# Have I been refused entry into the Federal Republic of Germany?

Tags: visa, germany, refusal, denied-entry

Due to a change of address, my German residence permit became invalid. They sent my residence permit to an officer in Frankfurt. Thats when he said that my visa is not valid due to a change in address. Hence I did not board the flight.

As I did not reach the German border, does this still count as refusal of entry into the Federal Republic of Germany?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does not, but could you edit the question to note the context in which you are being asked whether you were refused entry?

Comment: @phoog is correct: the answer to your question will depend upon _who is asking_. Depending upon the asker's language or laws, what happened to you may or may not be a "refusal of entry."

Comment: Keep in mind that the Federal Republic will have this occurrence in their records. If there is even a small chance that the Federal Republic immigration authorities will think what happened to you is a refusal of entry, then you should disclose it and explain what occurred. Because they know this occurred, your failure to disclose it will be seen as deception, and will by itself be grounds for refusal or ban.

Comment: If in doubt, tell them everything and let them decide if you were refused entry or not. Being forthcoming with the information can only help - if they think you are trying to conceal information (by not mentioning it), it can only go against you

Comment: The answer to this question depends on whether the immigration office thinks the OP has moved outside of Germany. I assume the OP has not, but the immigration office may assume otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

When you move, you are required to report your new address to the registry office. In some areas the registry office will report your new address to the immigration office, in others you must do this yourself.

If you do not do this and they have noticed that you have left, they will assume you have left the country permanenty and invalidate the residence permit.

Since you don't mention where you moved to, what you must do next will depend on that circumstance.

If you have moved within Germany and reported that to the local registry office, then you must bring the received registry certificate to the immigration office and, belatedly, report your change of address.

If you did not report your new address to the registry office, then you must do so now. This may incur a fine.

If you have moved outside of Germany, then you are no longer a resident of Germany. It will **not** be considered a refusal of entry.